# Performance implications of turning MTOM on for a WCF service

Tags: wcf, performance, mtom

Would there be any noticeable performance hit if MTOM is turned on for a WCF service that isn't actually transferring any binary over the wire?

Answer (score 1):

What is your binding set to now?
MTOM is faster than text (if binaries are sent), but slower than binary.

- choose text when the messages need to be readable
- choose binary with wcf to wcf communication
- choose mtom when you have binaries to send and have interoperability issues

You stated you have no binary data, in that case MTOM will be slower than text! It needs to pack the data into a MIME-document, and that takes time.

Regards,

M.

Comment: I'm trying to find out whether "packing the data into a MIME-document" would be close to negligible considering the standard overheads of a service call ...

Comment: Well, that is simple. I suppose you already have a working program. Send a message, without binaries, 10K times and perfmon (cpu and time) it with the different bindings.